# Using dlply with unsplit

Tags: r, plyr

I want to append a column to a dataframe that has the result of a cumulative function.  I can accomplish this with `unsplit`/`split`, like this

```
> set.seed(3)
> d <- data.frame(type=sample(c('a','b'),10,replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(10))
> d
   type         val
1     a  0.03012394
2     b  0.08541773
3     a  1.11661021
4     a -1.21885742
5     b  1.26736872
6     b -0.74478160
7     a -1.13121857
8     a -0.71635849
9     b  0.25265237
10    b  0.15204571
```

So I use `split`/`lapply`/`unsplit` to get my desired result

```
> d$sum <- unsplit(lapply(split(d,d$type), function(x) { cumsum(x$val)}), d$type)
> d
   type         val         sum
1     a  0.03012394  0.03012394
2     b  0.08541773  0.08541773
3     a  1.11661021  1.14673416
4     a -1.21885742 -0.07212326
5     b  1.26736872  1.35278645
6     b -0.74478160  0.60800486
7     a -1.13121857 -1.20334183
8     a -0.71635849 -1.91970032
9     b  0.25265237  0.86065723
10    b  0.15204571  1.01270293
```

And this is the desired result.  But I'd really like to use the simplified syntax of `plyr` in this case.  So I tried

```
> d$sum2 <- unsplit(dlply(d, .(type), summarise, cumsum(val)), d$type)
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'
```

The output of `dlply` and the `lapply`/`split` are almost the same, except that the `dlply` has some extra junk that I think `unsplit` will ignore, and the `dlply` output has re-indexed the row.names.  I think this latter is what the complaint is.

Also to note that I am aware that I can approach this with `ddply`/`transform`

```
> ddply(d, .(type), transform, sum2=cumsum(val))                                
   type         val         sum        sum2
1     a  0.03012394  0.03012394  0.03012394
2     a  1.11661021  1.14673416  1.14673416
3     a -1.21885742 -0.07212326 -0.07212326
4     a -1.13121857 -1.20334183 -1.20334183
5     a -0.71635849 -1.91970032 -1.91970032
6     b  0.08541773  0.08541773  0.08541773
7     b  1.26736872  1.35278645  1.35278645
8     b -0.74478160  0.60800486  0.60800486
9     b  0.25265237  0.86065723  0.86065723
10    b  0.15204571  1.01270293  1.01270293
```

This won't work in my case, because as you can see, this has the side effect of rearranging the rows to be out of order.  If there's some argument to `ddply` that would not rearrange the rows, then this would be perfect for my purposes.

Comment: If you need to preserve the original order, can you just simply add an index column and then sort by that column to restore the original order?

Comment: @VictorK. - Yes, that's an option, but I have to do this a lot as part of a data processing pipeline, and there are multiple factors involved; so there would be a lot of sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try `dplyr` instead? In contrast to `ddply`, it keeps the original order.

```
library(dplyr)
d %.%
  group_by(type) %.%
  mutate(sum = cumsum(val))
# Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
# Groups: type
# 
#    type         val         sum
# 1     a  0.03012394  0.03012394
# 2     b  0.08541773  0.08541773
# 3     a  1.11661021  1.14673416
# 4     a -1.21885742 -0.07212326
# 5     b  1.26736872  1.35278645
# 6     b -0.74478160  0.60800486
# 7     a -1.13121857 -1.20334183
# 8     a -0.71635849 -1.91970032
# 9     b  0.25265237  0.86065723
# 10    b  0.15204571  1.01270293
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of dplyr; same author as plyr and intended as the successor. Syntax is a little more verbose, but otherwise looks appealing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use use `ave`?

```
d$sum <-   # absolutely terrible name for a variable
  ave( d$val, d$type, FUN=cumsum)
```

The `lapply( split(d, d$type) , func)`-approach is overkill for a function that will only operate on one vector at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately, the real problem does involve multiple columns as input to the accumulator function. Ave is a fantastic function to keep in my toolbox, though.

Comment: Then you should post an example problem that adequately illustrates the problem. We are perfectly capable of working on multiple columns if that is the task ... if you can specify it. Use either `lapply(split(...))` or `do.call(rbind, by(...))`

Comment: I agree with @BondedDust. Both answers solved your problem as it was described in your question, didn't they? Please avoid making your question a moving target.

Comment: @Henrik Yes, they both solved the problem as stated, which is why I upvoted them both -- I realized that not providing the details made the `ave` solution workable (my fault).  Note that in my question I did show one working solution to my problem, so I was not just looking for a way to solve it, but rather a way to solve it within the `plyr` syntax.  Your, answer, at least, addressed that directly.